# How to export all tables within an Sybase 12.5 database to multiple flat files?

Tags: export, export-to-csv, sybase, sap-ase, isql

My customers runs an very old (seems to me) Sybase 12.5.2 database. I want/need to export all tables from a database to multiple (for each table) flat (text) files. I have access to ISQL command line prompt with the admin user. I havent worked ever with an Sybase database before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise (ASE) allows multiple databases to be hosted. You don't specify whether only one of the databases in the database server needs to be exported or if all of them do.

For each database, the following query will list the names of the tables

```sql
select name from sysobjects where type = 'U'
```

Sybase ASE also comes with a tool called "bcp" which stands for "Bulk Copy". It is an easy way of creating a flat file of a table's contents.

```
bcp database.schema.table out file_name -c -U username -S server_name
```

It has more options that may be of interest, especially around field and row terminators. Documentation for the most relevant version (12.5.1) can be found here:

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc30191_1251/html/utility/BABGCCIC.htm

Answer (score 0):

i have been using BCP commands to export data from sybase environments.bcp is a command line utility which you can use it to export data from multiple types of databases

below is a very example and you can try it for
bcp Table Name out OUTPUT FILE PATH\FILENAME.dat -S SERVER NAME -U USERNAME -P PASSWORD -F Format -r row_terminator -e error output file path and name

You can create a batch file with such commands and do multiple exports on one hit.

If you have access to any ETL tool you can exporting the data using the same as well.